# Twitter bootstrap3 Include a responsive menu on every page without cut & paste. PHP not working seemingly

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, menu, include, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to using Twitter Bootstrap and dealing with page creation in general. I have a responsive menu that I want to use on every page without having to cut & paste the menu code. I have searched here and seen that I should use PHP includes etc, but the code doesn't work for me. I paste the below snippet into menu.php, include that in my html file and no menu is shown. (background, testing locally using MAMP)

Code example:

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
   <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Operations Reconciliation</a>
 </div>

 <!-- create the menu items and dropdown menus -->

 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Business domains<b class="caret"></b></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="cash.html">Cash</a></li>
         <li><a href="Securities.html">Securities</a></li>
         <li><a href="reconc.html">Reconciliation Maintenace</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="reference.html">Reference</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

recap & clarification; If I wrap that in a PHP script and include it, it doesn't appear on my page. Does PHP not support that level of markup tags? or simply put, how do I get this menu (above) on every page without a cut & paste job and adding to every single .html file?

I'm an 'engine' sort of guy, so this front end dabbling is new to me, the more explicit the answer the better. Thanks for taking the time to read. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, then you have to use

https://www.php.net/echo

The echo() function to Output the html to the website.